# Unexpected symbol Error for my Int varible

Tags: unexpected-token

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
class MoveEstimator
{
   static void Main()
   {
     string entry; 
     int base;
     base = 200;
     int rph = 150;
     int rpm = 2;
     int input;
     int hours; 
     int miles; 
     int total;
     
     WriteLine ("Enter number of hours for job >>");
     entry = ReadLine ();
     WriteLine ("Enter number of miles for job >>");
     string entryii = ReadLine ();

     hours = Convert.ToInt32(entry);
     miles = Convert.ToInt32(entryii);

     total = (base + rph*hours + rpm*miles);

  WriteLine ("For a move taking{0} hours and going {1}miles the estimate is {2}",hours,miles,total.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
     


   }
}
```

I keep getting a error saying that my integer variable "base" is a unexpected symbol. all i did is say int base;. how its that wrong. I am also getting a error for every time I reference it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the Stack Overflow!

`base` is a reserved keyword in C#, so you should give this variable any other name, for example `initialDistance`))

Comment: @RickyBascom could you vote up this answer, if it helped you?

Comment: OK, nevermind. Just leave it as accepted answer))